# Unable to play video recordings of AXIS Camera

Tags: axis

I have this old AXIS Camera "AXIS M1034-W Network Camera"

[image]

It does its job. However, in the camera's UI in Chrome, I cannot play the recordings. I can play them as files in Windows Explorer, but not thru Chrome UI, please see screenshots attached.

In the window that opens, it just says

```
Play Recording
rtsptextrtsp://dummyurl/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=mpeg4
```

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: 1. That `dummyurl` address looks very suspect 2. The `rtsptextrtsp` protocol needs a handler inside the web browser. Perhaps you've lost the Quicktime plugin that understands this

Comment: It's just a message it displays, the URL is real, look in the address bar. rtsptextrtsp needs quicktime? Is quicktime supported in Chrome?

Comment: I think it's QuickTime, but I'm not totally sure

Comment: Installed QuickTime. Same problem.

Comment: In that case sorry out of ideas